# Mrunit: how to set value comparator for MultiOutput test

Tags: java, mapreduce, mrunit

is there a way to set key/value Comparator to test MultiOutput in mrunit?

Based on my analysis:
The mrunit doesn't use key/value Comparators to test the equality of expected and actual values of multioutput.The key/value comparators are only used for single output key and value comparison.

The **TestDriver** class has separate methods for the single output and multioutput, which compares the expected and actual results.

```
validate(single outputs, orderMatters);
validate(multioutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with mrunit and is not fixed in a released version as of 1.1.0.  See the jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRUNIT-224  Potentially you could use the patch there to build your own version of mrunit.